# Windows Service start then stops immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-services

I've created a windows service that creates a Form in which a tool strip icon is created to manage a socket. I'm able to install through an installer created in Visual Studio, but when I go to Services and start my service it gives me an error saying it started and stopped immediately.

Here's the service code:

```
public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        ServiceName = "WizardServer";
        CanPauseAndContinue = false;
        CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        CanStop = true;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        try
        {
            connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler();  
            serviceThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(serviceTarget));
            alive = true;
            serviceThread.Start();
        }
        catch {}
    }

    private void serviceTarget()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1(connectionHandler));

        while (alive) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        try
        {
            connectionHandler.stop();
        }
        catch {}

        serviceThread.Abort();

        alive = false;
        Stop();
    }
```

PS: I've tested the form and it works just fine.

Comment: What does the event log divulge?

Comment: This usually means that there is an error happening on the start of the services.  You also have a blank try .... catch.  There may be an error you are swallowing and you need to capture that error to see what it is.  I usually use a text file to capture these errors, since you really can't see the errors from the service

Comment: Normally, windows services do not have UIs, and Microsoft strongly recommends that they don't. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Have you checked your event log?

Comment: @PaulieWaulie where can I see the log in release mode?

Comment: @DjBurb if I write to a file (on root), where would that file go?

Comment: @RicardoAmendoeira Go to Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer and then look in Windows Logs -> Application, there may be something useful in there.  I have to say that I do agree with hatchet, creating a UI for a service seems a little odd, services tend to be for executing code without a UI.

Comment: If this is running on a client machine, I would create a folder and store it in there.  You could just do that for troubleshooting and remove it later if you wish

Comment: Also look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx Starting with Vista, Microsoft built into Windows limitations for services that expose a user interface.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it! It was change of serviceName, canPauseAndContinue, etc... They couldn't be the onStart(). Moved them to the constructor and voila! And I did remove the UI, I can manage with the event log only. Thanks to all of you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and search many hours on google then i find solution. You can add following code in your code. Add `InitializeTimer()` in your class constructor.You should Set `oTimer.Enabled = true` and `oTimer.Start()` on `OnStart()` and `oTimer.Stop()` on `OnStop()`.

Code:

```
  void create()
    {
        string s = "";
    }
    void InitializeTimer()
    {
        oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
        oTimer.AutoReset = true;
        oTimer.Enabled = true;
        oTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(oTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    void oTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateFileData();
    }

    void CreateFileData()
    {
        string path = @"C:\SimpleWcfService\SimpleWindowsService\bin\Release\Singh.txt";
        StreamWriter oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        oStreamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        oStreamWriter.Close();
        oStreamWriter = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm incredibly late in answering this, but hopefully this will help anyone else having the same issue:

Changing the "Output type" in the Windows Service project's Properties fixed it for me.

1. In the Solution Explorer, find your project and double-click "Properties"
2. In the window that opens, go to the "Application" tab
3. Change the value under "Output type" to "Console Application"